# Как получить все View из ViewGroup?

Tags: java, android, android-customview

Здравствуйте. Просьба помочь с написанием первого виджета. Я не расчитываю на массовое использование, хочу сделать **чисто для себя**. Виджет будет наследоваться от `FrameLayout`. В `xml` нужно будет внутри виджета написать не менее одного `view`. Причём если разработчик напишет один `layout`, то он будет считаться за один `view`, независимо от количества `view` внутри него.

Помогите пожалуйста в одном. Каким образом можно получить все `view` внутри него, если их количество неизвестно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Количество View внутри ViewGroup можно получить с помощью [getChildCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount()), ссылку на каждый из них - с помощью [getChildAt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)).

```
int count = getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    View child = getChildAt(i);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо)) А ещё такой вопрос, куда это писать? У виджета сейчас три конструктора, выходит нужно создать метод для получения всех `view` и в каждом конструктора его вызывать? Или не надо все три конструктора?

Comment: В смысле куда? В любое место, в котором вам нужно что-то сделать с находящимися внутри вашего FrameLayout вьюхами. Если с ними ничего делать не надо, то никуда не писать.

Comment: @СергейГрушин вы можете вызывать один конструктор через другой через служебное слово `this`. Так же вы можете сделать отдельный метод инициализации и вызывать его во всех конструкторах, в зависимости от задачи. Почти во всех гайдах по кастомным `View` все это есть